# pthread with php 7.0.8 (ZTS)

Tags: php, nginx, pthreads, debian, php-7

I would like use pthreads with php 7.0.8 (ZTS) (Manually compiled and configured)
I have add the followinG configuration during compiling of php :

```
--enable-maintainer-zts \
--enable-pthreads=shared \
--with-tsrm-pthreads \
```

> NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 25546
>
> NOTICE: ready to handle connections

I add pthread extension with pecl : `pecl install pthreads-3.1.6` and I add extension=pthreads.so into my php.ini. But after restarting php7-fpm, php-fpm not running :

> NOTICE: Finishing ...
>
> NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!

I have a 502 nginx error.

How I can add this extension in my php.ini without exit php-fpm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use php-cli for use pthreads. You can create a second php.ini configuration for CLI :

- First, copy if not exist your php.ini to php-cli.ini :

  ```
  cp /PATH_OF_YOUR_PHP_INSTALLATION/php.ini /PATH_OF_PHP_INSTALLATION/php-cli.ini
  ```
- Then, install pthreads with PECL (if php is compiled with 
  `--enable-maintainer-zts \ --enable-pthreads=shared \ --with-tsrm-pthreads` )

  ```
  pecl install pthreads
  ```
- Then, add the configuration of the extension into your php-cli.ini :

  ```
  echo "extension=/PATH_OF_EXTENSION/pthreads.so" >>/PATH_OF_PHP_INSTALLATION/php-cli.ini
  ```
- Finnaly, restart your php7-fpm service :

  ```
  service php7-fpm restart
  ```

You can test the pthread installation is working to create a test class and execute it with php :
Create file : ImportWorker.php

```
<?php
class ImportWorker extends Worker {
    private $data;

    public function __construct($_data) {
        $this->data = $_data;//
    }

    public function run(){
        var_dump("Worker test");
    }
}
```

Execute that : `php ImportWorker.php` -> If you have any errors, that is pthreads is not working.